# Laravel - signed route with 404 error for an email unsubscribe link

Tags: laravel, email, hyperlink, unsubscribe

I have an unsubscribe link for emails, but when I click on the link I get an error 404.

this is my code.

First, this is the generation for unsubscribe link with signed route (link is okay)

```
private function generateUnsubscribeLink($meoId, $email)
{
    return URL::signedRoute(
        'meo.confirm-unsubscribe', [
            'meo' => $meoId,
            'email' => $email
        ]
    );
}
```

next, this is my web.php routes

```
Route::get('/unsubscribe/{meo}/{email}', 'MeoMailController@confirmUnsubscribe')->name('meo.confirm-unsubscribe');
Route::post('/unsubscribe/confirmed/{meo}/{email}', 'MeoMailController@unsubscribe')->name('meo.unsubscribe');
```

and finally, this is my controller

```
public function confirmUnsubscribe(Request $request, Meo $meo, MailRecipient $email){
        if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
            abort(401);
        }

        return view('mail.confirm_unsubscribe', compact(['request', 'meo', 'email']));
    }

    public function unsubscribe(Meo $meo, MailRecipient $email)
    {
          $email->state = MailRecipientState::UNSUBSCRIBED;
          $email->save();

        return view('mail.unsubscribed');
    }
```

the final result of this is when I click on the unsubscribe link is an error 404

[image]

the link is unsubscribe/meoId/email@example.com?SIGNEDROUTE

what's wrong here?

In the past, I used the same method but without email (only using meoId), and was working correctly

Comment: it's mean your email in `MailRecipient` is not found

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur can I use only $email in confirmUnsubscribe?

Comment: I dont know what is `MailRecipient`? a model or a library function?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur a model

Comment: so yes, check  on my answer for full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `MailRecipient $email` in method arg to `$email` then find that model manually like `$email = MailRecipient::where('email',$email)->first()`. should be like:

```
public function confirmUnsubscribe(Request $request, Meo $meo, $email){
 if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
abort(401);
}

$email = MailRecipient::where('email',$email)->first();
return view('mail.confirm_unsubscribe', compact(['request', 'meo', 'email']));
}

public function unsubscribe(Meo $meo, $email)
{
$email = MailRecipient::where('email',$email)->first();

$email->state = MailRecipientState::UNSUBSCRIBED;
$email->save();

return view('mail.unsubscribed');
}
```